# google maps infowindow like google's original

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-api

[image: google's original infowindow]

Is there any **complete solutions** to make such infowindows, or I should do it myself?

FAQ:
In google map api you can render some template as its content.
[api reference](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindow)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, but you can create a Google Map when signed in with a Google account, and style the iFrame with css rules. Your created map will  embed with your choice of dropped pins.

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/google-maps

Comment: question is obviously specific, if i write "infowindow" together i means google api v3 infowindows. you can make your own infowindow by rendering some template as its content. what do i find for? i find for this renderer